# i am not understanding what that mean in laravel route "Route::get()->where();"

Tags: php, laravel

how function call another function using this "->"
for example "Route::get()->name()"or "Route::get()->where()"

Comment: maybe [This](https://github.com/miladzamir/sledge/blob/master/src/Builder/Form.php) class can help you. when you return $this you can access to another methods like:  `title()->placeholder()->validate()` Tip: this is not belongs to Laravel its just a class can create html element from controller

Comment: Look up "method chaining"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you can set routes using this code, if you set a route and you want to name it you can add the `->name()` method after your declaration.

One example:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('LandingPage');
```

`landing page` is the name of the route `/`.

Comment: what that "->"mean between two methods get()and name().

Comment: That means that for that specific method, in this case `->get()` you can run another method which will perform an action for that and only that method. So it is not necessary to add a name but if you want to you can add it.

Comment: `->` means **access operator**.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Pipeline in laravel that might answer your question or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XqEJO-wt7s&t=645s&ab_channel=Coder%27sTape) is a quick video on it

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two questions itself.

Lets look into `Route::get('/url', 'ControllerName@functionName)->name('route.name');`

`url` is what you wish to display in the browser url.

`ControllerName` is the name of your controller where your function exist.

`functionName` is the name of your function that you wish your url for that functional behavior.

`route.name` would be the name for your easy access of the function through out your  project where you would like to process as reference. Eg: if you call `route('route.name')` it would mean that your logic has to access this function and process accordingly to your logic within the function.

Example:
This way your action will end up at `route('route.name')` to what ever was in that function.

```
public function index() {
       // some logic ....
       return redirect()->route('route.name');
}
```

Now, lets look into

`Route::get('/url/{id}', 'ControllerName@functionName)->where('id', '[0-9]+');`

Here, all the keywords are same as above example except it has a **where** clause. What the where clause does is that, it makes sure that the `{id}` passed in the url needs to be within the `'[0-9]+'` parameters. Please look into the documentation for more details.
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters[enter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters%5Benter) link description here][1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters)